# How to run a sqlite script from Emacs

Tags: sqlite, emacs

I'd like to edit a `sqlite` script in an `emacs` buffer. I wonder how to run this script(or buffer) from `emacs`.
Any good idea for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite is supported out of box in the built-in `sql-mode` that is automatically enabled for files with `.sql` extension.  You can press `M-x sql-sqlite` to get access to your sqlite database.

After that you can use commands like `C-c C-r` to send the region to interpreter and see the results (there are also other commands like send paragraph, send buffer, etc. - see them in the SQL menu.

EmacsWiki has a [page about this mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SqlMode) where you can find more recipes, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. And I set up a file with `.sql` extention. Then I tried your way, but find that all `send...` commands in the SQL menu are in grey which means unaccessible. How to deal with that?

Comment: You need to execute M-x command first to open a session